# How to get random-steps decorated tables?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularx, decorations

I use tikz's `decoration={random steps}` a lot in a document for boxes and separator lines. In the same document I have tables set as `tabularx`, but the cell backgrounds / lines in those tables are straight. Is there a simple way to use something similar to the random steps from tikz in regular tables, both as cell backgrounds as well as as line separators? Or is it easier to just recreate such the table in tikz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is not very nice, but you can try with a TiKZ `matrix`.  Be careful, a `matrix` doesn't behave like a tabular, so drawing vertical and horizontal divisions is not so easy.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix, decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={random steps, segment length=3pt}]

\matrix (a) [draw, decorate, matrix of nodes, column sep=0pt, row sep=0pt]
{
First & Second & Third \\
This is longer & a & \dots \\
};
\draw[decorate] (a.west)--(a.east);
\draw[decorate] (a.north-|a-2-1.east) -- (a.south-|a-2-1.east);
\draw[decorate] (a.north-|a-1-2.east) -- (a.south-|a-1-2.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```